# org - How to reference var in CALL

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

```
#+NAME: fun1
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var var1="val1"
(format "%s" var1)
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: fun2
#+HEADER: :var var2="val2"
#+CALL: fun1(var2)

#+NAME: fun3
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var var2="val2" var3=fun1(var2)
(format "%s" var3)
#+END_SRC
```

Both fun2 and fun3 complain `Reference 'var2' not found in this buffer`

**Update:**
I need to simplify this form

```
#+NAME: funA
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var varA="valA"
(format "%s" varA)
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: funA2E
#+CALL: funA[:var varF="valF"](funB(funC(funD(funE(varF)))))

#+CALL: funA2E("foo")

#+CALL: funA2E("bar")

#+CALL: funA2E("baz")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the literal value of the argument inline in the `CALL`.  For example:

```
#+NAME: fun1
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var var1="val1"
(format "%s" var1)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: fun1
: val1

#+NAME: fun2
#+CALL: fun1(var1="val2")

#+RESULTS: fun2
: val2

#+NAME: fun3
#+CALL: fun1("val3")

#+RESULTS: fun3
: val3
```

Your `fun2` fails because the `HEADER` line cannot be applied to `CALL`.  Instead, you have to use a `CALL: <name>[<inside header arguments>](<arguments>)[<end header arguments>]` syntax (see [org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-code-blocks.html)), as in this example:

```
#+NAME: fun4
#+CALL: fun1[:var var1="val4"]()

#+RESULTS: fun4
: val4
```

Your `fun3` fails because you can't refer back to values of previous variables defined in the same `:var` header argument.  The complete syntax for `:var` is described in the [relevant section of the org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/var.html#var)

**Update:** Responding to your edit and clarification, I do not think this is possible using the CALL syntax, which is relatively inflexible.  However, with lisp functions we can construct a string representation of the nested source block call, and then use `org-babel-ref-resolve` to do the equivalent of the CALL line.

For example, I define a source block `funX` to be the basic building block (this function can be any in any language supported by babel).

```
#+NAME: funX
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var a="A" s="X"
(format "%s.%s.%s" a s a)
#+END_SRC
```

Then, I have a lisp source block with a single parameter `s`, which constructs a deeply nested call to the `funX` block, with `s` inserted as a parameter to the innermost function:

```
#+name: funABCDE
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var s="\" ¡Hola! \""
  (defun funX (a s) (format "funX(\"%s\", %s)" a s))
  (defun nested-funX (s)
    (funX "a" (funX "b" (funX "c" (funX "d" (funX "e" s))))))
  (org-babel-ref-resolve (nested-funX s))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: a.b.c.d.e. ¡Hola! .e.d.c.b.a
```

We can then re-use that source block in a CALL line with a different value of `s`:

```
#+CALL: funABCDE("\" Nǐ hǎo! \"")

#+RESULTS:
: a.b.c.d.e. Nǐ hǎo! .e.d.c.b.a
```

Unfortunately, it is necessary to use an extra pair of escaped quotation marks in the argument for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but how can I simplify a nested CALL with variables like the updated description above?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "simplify", but I have added an example of chaining (nesting) functions with a varying second parameter.  Does that help?

Comment: How can I use #+CALL: funY("Hello!") instead of the long call chain? Because I may `repeat #+CALL: funY("Hello!")`, but I don't want to copy `#+CALL: funX("A", funX("B", funX("C", funX("D", funX("E", " Hello! ")))))` many times. Also, the word "Hello" can be different in repeats

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification.  I see what you want now, and I don't think it is possible.  The programming features of the CALL syntax and header arguments are very limited – it is not a full programming language.  In particular, it is not possible to add a "new" variable to a CALL statement, such as the varF in your funA2E

Comment: I found a relevant thread on the org mailing list. This explains more fully why it is not possible, and lists several alternative approaches that might work: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-01/msg00003.html

Comment: I did find a solution that is quite neat – see my recent edit.

Comment: Awesome, it exactly solved the problem! :D